# Variable and string concat to select variable in lua

Tags: variables, lua, global-variables, computercraft

I have a set of variables that holds quantity info and x to select the one I use. How can I concatenate the letter s and var x and have it read as s2 or s3 etc. The code I managed to find does not work.

```
x = 2 
s1 = false
s2 = 64
s3 = 64
s4 = 64
s5 = 0

if s2 >= 0 then
x = 2
elseif s3 >= 0 then
x = 3
elseif s4 >= 0 then
x = 4
elseif s5 >= 0 then
x = 5
end

if turtle.placeDown() then
 tryUp()
 turtle.select(1)
 _G["s"..x] = _G["s"..x] - 1 
end
```

Comment: `_G["s"..x]` looks correct. How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: The code [works](https://eval.in/170740). Though in general doing this with a local table of your own is better than using _G but <shrug>.

Comment: Your `if-elseif-end` branchy structure could also be transformed using the same trick: `for i=2,5 do if _G['s'..i]>=0 then x=i break end end`

Comment: the error i get is: attempt to preform arithmetic __sub on nil and number

I am doing this in computercraft (if you didn't already know) the version of Lua is Luaj-jse 2.0.3

Comment: The reason the code looks correct is that there are no declarations for s1, s2, s3, s4, s5. So, we assume they are global. But, if there is unseen code that declares as local then using _G won't work.

Comment: Thank you Tom!

To correct code add

    _G.s2 = s2
    _G.s3 = s3
    _G.s4 = s4
    _G.s5 = s5

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to do that?

My suggestion to improve your code would be something like this:

```
local s = {false, 64, 64, 64, 0}

for i = 2, #s do
  if s[i] >= 0 then
    x = s[i]
  end
end

if turtle.placeDown() then
  tryUp()
  turtle.select(1)
  x = x-1
end
```

Using a loop makes the code somewhat neater, and there is no real need for you to use global variables. If you insist on using _G with the string concatenation with your original code, try this:

```
x = 2 
s1 = false
s2 = 64
s3 = 64
s4 = 64
s5 = 0

if s2 >= 0 then
x = "2" --Notice the string here
elseif s3 >= 0 then
x = "3"
elseif s4 >= 0 then
x = "4"
elseif s5 >= 0 then
x = "5"
end

if turtle.placeDown() then
 tryUp()
 turtle.select(1)
 _G["s"..x] = _G["s"..x] - 1 
end
```

This replaces all the x values with strings instead of numbers, which was probably what was causing the error